# I am getting following error in Ubuntu 18 although I haven't set any password for SQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am unable to find the solution for this.

Comment: Is any answer a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
mysql -u root
```

This will not prompt for a password.

Comment: It shows the same error 1045.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html) there are multiple cases:

1. There was set a random password during installation

   - Initialize the data directory if it wasn't during installation: `mysqld --initialize`
   - Get the generated password by looking in the error log: `cat /var/log/mysql/error.log | grep root@localhost`
   - Log in with that password: `mysql -u root -p` (in some cases you have to run this with `sudo`)
   - Change the password: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`
2. There was **not** set a random password during installation

   - Initialize the data directory if it wasn't during installation: `mysqld --initialize-insecure`
   - Log in with that password: `mysql -u root --skip-password` (maybe you have to try also with `sudo`)
   - Change the password: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`

Hope that helps.